# Magento 2 get static image url in custom field type renderer

Tags: magento2, adminform

If I need to insert image inside admin form inside function _prepareForm I simply call this:

```
$this->getViewFileUrl("Company_Module::images/icon.png")
```

But this doesn't work if I call it within custom field renderer

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer;
class Customtype extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement{
  var_dump($this->getViewFileUrl("Company_Module::images/icon.png")); //returns null
}
```

What would be a proper way to get image url in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject this class into your constructor:
`\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository`
Assigning the instance to `$this->_assetRepo`

Then you can make the getViewFileUrl method:

```
    public function getViewFileUrl($fileId, array $params = [])
    {
        try {
            return $this->_assetRepo->getUrlWithParams($fileId, $params);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```